# Download a file (Python 3.4.1 Win8) with no direct link to filename

Tags: python, download

I wrote the following simple code (with the help of stackoverflow, thanks!) to download a file from a url link:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.url.com/file.pdf"
response = requests.get(url)
output = open('file.pdf', 'wb')
output.write(response.content)
```

The code works fine provided that I have a file name in the url. However, some links directly open a pdf with a url that does not contain a file name. Does requests have a way to handle this?

Some additional info: the url's in question contain the string ".cfm?" which I found refers to cold fusion markup language. I hope this will help someone in finding a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

When a browser is given a response with a file, it'll look for the filename as part of the URL, but if there is a [`Content-Disposition` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) (originally a MIME header but used in HTTP too) with a filename parameter then the filename is taken from that.

`requests` doesn't give you any specific assistance; do so yourself instead:

```
import cgi
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

def filename_from_response(response):
    cdisp = response.headers.get('content-disposition')
    if cdisp:
        _, params = cgi.parse_header(cdisp)
        if 'filename' in params:
            return filename
    last_part = urlsplit(response.url).path.rpartition('/')[-1]
    return last_part
```

Comment: I used resp.headers to get the header information. It returned {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Thu, 21 Aug 2014 15:12:02 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5'}. should this be where the Content-Disposition header is?

Comment: @cptwinky: `Content-Disposition` is an optional header. You got HTML, not a PDF there, in any case, clearly that's not meant to be treated as a downloadable file.

Comment: The files I am trying to access are free and open. When the download link is clicked in the browser, a pdf appears in the browser window and can be downloaded. The response headers I posted above are from a copy-and-paste of the url that is present when the pdf is open

Comment: @cptwinky: but that's not a PDF response. Perhaps the HTML loads JavaScript that then loads the PDF?

Comment: I don't know. I guess that's my issue. It seems if I can download the file manually I should be able to do it with python

Comment: @cptwinky: you can, if you have a URL to it and perhaps additional information in headers (such as cookies, the referer, other browser-identifying information a server could be using). But *I* cannot help you any further because your question is lacking enough detail as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is a website containing multiple pdf files for download. I would like to retrieve a large number of them without having to manually navigate to each link. The url for each file contains a consistent naming scheme (with dates) which means I can loop through the url name strings to download each one.