# Downloading file from URL using Python - Unknown error

Tags: python, download

I am having a problem downloading a file from a specific Korean URL. When I googled how to download files through URL, it recommended many solutions such as using urlretrieve, urlopen, wget. However, whenever I try, it saves a 0 byte PDF file and it does not return any error message.

So I tired using other program such as Postman or J2downloader and they saved `pdf.do` with 0 byte. I know `.do` could be opened with Acrobat Reader but the size tells me that it was not able to download the contents.

The URL of the site is http://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/pdf.do?rcp_no=20210218000576&dcm_no=7808922. If I open it through a website, it downloads correctly.

Now I am not sure whether it's my code problem or the site mechanism is different. If it's the websites mechanism, could you tell me how to make it work on using Python?

**Code that I tried**

```py
final_url = http://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/pdf.do?rcp_no=20210218000576&dcm_no=7808922
1. 
    urlretrieve(final_url, "./down2.pdf")
2.
    with open("down.pdf",'wb') as file:
        response = requests.get(final_url, allow_redirects=True)
        print(response.content)
        file.write(response.content)
3. 
    mem = urlopen(final_url).read()
    with open("down.pdf",'wb') as file:
        file.write(mem)
        file.close()
4.
    wget.download(final_url, "my download folder")
```

Comment: Do any of the alternatives in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035123/what-command-to-use-instead-of-urllib-request-urlretrieve) work?

Comment: no... I tried all of the alternatives in the post you provided but it only downloaded 0byte pdf file @RandomDavis

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628699/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-which-redirects)? I think all the techniques you're trying only work for a non-redirecting direct file link, which yours might not be.

Comment: I also thought it might be a redirection issue and I tried `allow_redirects=True` but it did not work and also it had same url even after adding that parameter.

Comment: I'd take a look at these and see if any of them help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988951 https://stackoverflow.com/q/25430219 Also when downloading the file, what's the actual download URL? It could be something predictable.

Comment: When I looked for headers it was the result `{'Date': 'Thu, 18 Feb 2021 20:00:07 GMT', 'Set-Cookie': 'WMONID=s8FRMj229G0; Expires=Sat, 19-Feb-2022 5:0:7 GMT; Path=/, PDFJSESSIONID=3BK384GDNwYyLXcM3xtag1IeqQX1Xy4tw17iCGOXVpaehxHcJlRK9Q29vdfVRjlo.ZG1fcGRmL2ZpbGVyM19wZGZfbXMx; Path=/pdf; HttpOnly', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '0'}` I don't exactly see that it is pdf type but the downloads gives pdf file.The link that I posted is the actual downlad URL. When clicked, it automatically downloads the file.

Comment: I was wondering whether the 'user-agent' might affect the result so I copied the user-agent from the chrome and added to the program and it worked. Guess the website only wants browsers to access it. Thank you for the help @RandomDavis, it made me think of adding headers.

Comment: Cool, you can self-answer this question with what worked if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the website seems to only allow browsers to download the files. So the solution was to get the user-agent header from browser and input into the program.

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(final_url, headers=headers)

with open("down.zip",'wb') as file:
    print(response.content)
    file.write(response.content)
```